# Android clicking a button inside a webview

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a button inside a webview, I'm using the following code :

```
package com.example.tests;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Webview extends Activity {

   private WebView browser;

   @Override        
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
      browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
      browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
      browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
   }


   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url); 
          view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
          {
              @JavascriptInterface
            public void performClick() throws Exception
            {
                Log.d("LOGIN::", "Clicked");
                 Toast.makeText(Webview.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          }, "login");
         return true;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

As for the html page :

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function js1() 
{
document.loginform.method="post";
document.loginform.action = "https://example.com/chechlogin.asp";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform">
<input type="text" name="empcode" value="58686" /><br/>
<input type="password" name="emppassNTL" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_id" onclick="btnLogin.performClick();" />
```

When clicking on the button a toast message should be shown, well it's not working, any help please ?

Comment: also see this http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_id" onclick="btnLogin.performClick();" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_id" onclick="login.performClick();" />
```

Because your `Interface` name is **login** not **btnLogin**

For more info see this best post [Android webview JavaScript Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: @user3012088 what is in your log?

Comment: Thank you it worked, but the problem is when I click the button for the first time it won't do anything, when I click it again it'll give the toast message

Comment: @user3012088 Happy to help,enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

A tip: You can override opened links (`<a href=`) with the WebView:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if ( url.equals("http://www.google.com") ){
            Log.d("debugging","we can do something here");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post : http://vshivam.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/week-2-5-androidjsbridge/
This is how you'd go about accessing android methods from JS.

Do comment if things are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your javascript.js file in the assest folder do your coding whatever you want.

Inside the html you can add `onclick="callFunction();` to any the tag. and you are done...